# R reverse behaviour of bquote

Tags: r, metaprogramming

`bquote` function allows to evaluate parts of the expression which are wrapped in `.()` call. For example,

```
a <- 2
b <- 100
bquote(.(2 * a) * x + .(log10(b)))
```

would return

```
4 * x + 2
```

I want to rewrite this function to evaluate everything except for things inside `.()` call. This is the desired behavior:

```
a <- 2
b <- 100
bquote(2 * a * .(x) + log10(b))

> 4 * x + 2
```

I understand that to do so I have to go over the [abstract syntax tree](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#structure-of-expressions) and evaluate brunches without `.()` call in them but I couldn't handle all this recursion.

Could you help me to write such a function?

Comment: Is there a use-case to justify yet another new syntax? And how should it know to evaluate the first `*` but not the second or `+`?

Comment: Maybe you could step back and say what the goal of having such a function would be.

Comment: The reason behind this is to simplify computer generated equations before plotting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subst` will substitute all variables except those within .(...) and the `simplify` function will simplify sub-trees that have no variables -- omit the simplify part if simplification is not needed.  No packages are used.

```
subst <- function(e) {
   if (typeof(e) == "language") {
      if (identical(e[[1]], as.name("."))) e[[2]]
      else {
        if (length(e) > 1) e[-1] <- lapply(as.list(e[-1]), subst)
        e
      }
   } else {
      eval(e)
   }
}

simplify <- function(e) {
  if (typeof(e) == "language") {
     if (length(all.vars(e))) {
         if (length(e) > 1) {
           e[-1] <- lapply(as.list(e[-1]), simplify)
           e
         } else e
     } else eval(e)
  } else e
}

inverse_bquote <- function(x, SIMPLIFY = TRUE) {
   result <- subst(substitute(x))
   if (SIMPLIFY) simplify(result) else result
}
```

Now test it out.

```
a <- 2
b <- 100

inverse_bquote(2 * a * .(x) + log10(b))
## 4 * x + 2

# without simplification

inverse_bquote(2 * a * .(x) + log10(b), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
## 2 * 2 * x + log10(100)
```

**Update:** Added simplification.  Made it optional.