# R store expressions in data.frame

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I have a matrix of computer generated equations. Each equation is solved to produce a single number. Resulting numeric matrix is then fed to the `solve` function. For plotting results over a variable, this has to be repeated N times.

I want to speed up the calculations by modifying AST of the equations and simplify them using [these functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48053760/5745120) before evaluating.

The problem I encountered is that I cannot properly store modified equations of types `expression` or `language` in matrix or data.frame. For example:

```
foo <- data.frame(matrix(expression(NA), nrow = 100, ncol = 100))
# does not work
# apply(foo, MARGIN = c(1,2), function(x) {expression(1+1)})
for (i in c(1:100)) {for (j in c(1:100)) {foo[i,j] <- expression(1+1)}}
```

Resulting data.frame `foo` is 3.1Mb even for the shortest expression. Real equations are even bigger and have awful subset time. Is there a way to store these types efficiently?

Comment: Why not allocate the matrix of numeric output instead of a matrix of expressions so that, as you loop through, you can solve each expression as a one-off, and store just the output in the matrix?

Comment: @AdamO If I, for example, would plot `f(x)=a*x+log(c+d)` over `x`, I would recalculate `log(x+d)` for each point. The idea is to precalculate such brunches of AST to save time. Just catching numeric output would mean having to do this precalculation for each point. Doing so would make no sense.

Comment: Is there really no common structure to these expressions? Can you not capture only the general parameters and pass them into a function (or set of functions) to evaluate the numeric output?

Comment: @AdamO These equations are generated based on the user input from large number of separate chunks.

Comment: store the user input as a character? Evaluate by parsing into an expression?

Comment: @AdamO No, evaluating user input "as is" is a bad idea. Generate equations based on user choices. In my case user specifies equation kind and some its parameters by selecting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with this I've found so far is to store expressions in function. I create a function:

```
out <- function() {
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
}
```

Then I append expressions to it:

```
n <- 3
for (i in c(1:100)) {
  for (j in c(1:100)) {
    body(out)[[n]] <- substitute(m[i, j] <- f+i+j, list(i=i, j=j))
    n <- n + 1
  }
  n <- n + 1
}
```

Finally, I append the `return` statement and add arguments to the function:

```
body(out)[[length(body(out))+1]] <- quote(m)
formals(out) <- alist(f=)
```

To speed things up for the repeated evaluation of the resulted function, I compile it to bytecode:

```
outc <- cmpfun(out)
```

Upon calling this function returns a numeric matrix of executed equations, so no subsetting is needed. It is really big though. `out` and `outc` are both 56Mb.